# Laravel Cache seems don't work properly

Tags: caching, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel. I use Cache Facade to cache some data on the server, the cache driver is "file". Below is part of my code has problem:

```
            // at the very beginning, forget the cache item, and run only once
            if (Cache::has('votes_record')) {
                Cache::forget('votes_record');
            }

            ...
            ...


line 147    if (Cache::has('votes_record')) {
line 148        $votes_record = Cache::get('votes_record');
line 149        if (array_key_exists($input['From'], $votes_record)){
                    // do something here
                }
            } else {
                // first time, create this array
                $score = 0;              
                $votes_record = array(
                    $input['From'] => array(
                        'score' => $score,
                    )
                )
                Cache::put('votes_record', $votes_record, 60);
            }
```

above code (from line 147) will run multiple times, this is the error message: `exception 'ErrorException' with message 'array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given' in /app/Http/Controllers/VotesController.php:149`

So it said the **$votes_record** is null, but I check if this Cache item exists on line 147, and it pass the check, so it means the Cache item exists, why it return null on line 148?

above error doesn't happen all the time, it looks happen randomly, when there are a lot of requests to call this piece of code(from line 147),

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the value stored in 'votes_record' is null? (like $a = null, so $a is present but is equal to null)

Comment: I don't think so, because I run: Cache::forget('votes_record'); at very beginning, and you can see I use: Cache::put('votes_record', $votes_record, 60); to give value, it should not be null, right?